Can I take moving sand art on the plane?
I bought some moving sand art that has both liquid and sand in it with out thinking about how I am going to take it on the plane so I am wondering if there is a way to take it on the plane?

Domestic or International flight?

How big is this piece? Do you have any checked luggage?

If it's got liquid in it, then any restriction on carrying liquids in cabin baggage will apply. You should be able to carry it in checked baggage (just make sure it's well packed). But it'll depend to some extent what the liquid is: I'd guess it's water, which should be OK but if it's something flammable you may have a problem. There may be biosecurity rules around sand as there are for soil, but if it's been chemically treated I'd guess it's OK.

In addition to the earlier questions, what are the countries of origin and destination (if different)?

The TSA tells us that sand (alone) is allowed in both carry-on and checked luggage. But if there's a large quantity of liquid (100ml) then of course the liquids rule kicks in...
